# Incorrect_Resource_URL virtualbox

Tags: resource-urls

Running civicrm 4.7.26 -> upgrade 4.7.29 error message  Incorrect Resource URL 
in joomla and drupal. Running civicrm under virtualbox with url http://localhost:10080
absoulte path will be accepted by configuration, but error message still warns.
in the configuration section resource url a click of the first ?  will show the correct absoulute path and url varibales
neither the absoulte path nor the url varibales works
any suggestions
try configuration unter settings.php 
global $civicrm_setting;
$civicrm_setting['Extension Preferences']['ext_repo_url'] = false;

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of this check.

My guess is that you're forwarding port 80 on the virtual machine to port 10080 on the host machine.  However, the check, since it runs over HTTP internally on the virtual machine, is checking port 80.

That SHOULD work properly to detect whether your paths are correct, but I haven't tested this scenario.  If you know for a fact that your resource URLs are correct, there's no harm in selecting "Never remind me about this again" and ignoring the message.

Answer (score 0):

I found this 'incorrect resource URL' message and don't know what it is flagging - the resource url set up in civicrm_settings.php is correct. What exactly is the test for resource url?